# How to delete the first 3 characters if the first one is a capital letter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have an array `["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]`.

I want to delete the first three characters if the first one is capital in a loop so that I can use each output.

My desired output after the first loop is

```
["Ab,Aa", "Bb,Bd", "Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
```

I am trying in the following but I am stuck.

```
arr1 =  ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
def eliminatecolumn(arr)
  arr.map do |item| 
    if item[0]=~/[A-Z]/
     item[0..2]=''
    end
  end
end
eliminatecolumn(arr1)
```

I get `["", "", "", nil, nil, nil]` with this.

I am new to Ruby.

Comment: why you reverting the change I did,,? *block* parameter should come after `do`.. .. It is a style. Your `if` statement also wrongly written..

Comment: I think it happened the same time as I was editing. I am sorry.

Comment: @shin What is your final requirement?

Comment: What are you stuck on? that approach seems to work fine.

Comment: shin, if you found at least one answer helpful, please consider selecting one.

Answer (score 4):

**Code**

```
a.map { |str| str.sub(/..,/) { |s| (s == s.capitalize) ? "" : s } }
  #=> ["Ab,Aa", "Bb,Bd", "Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
```

**Explanation**

When [String#sub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-sub) is given a block, the match is passed to the block and the block determines the replacement.  (`nil` is passed if there is no match.)  For example, when

```
str = "Ac,Ab,Aa"
```

the match is

```
s = "Ac,Ab,Aa"[/..,/] #=> "Ac,"
```

so

```
(s == s.capitalize) ? "" : s
```

becomes

```
("Ac," == "Ac,") ? "" : "Ac,"
```

causing `"Ac,"` to be replaced with an empty string. By constrast, if

```
str => "aA,aC,aD"
```

the match is

```
s = "aA,aC,aD"[/..,/] #=> "aA,"
```

so

```
(s == s.capitalize) ? "" : s }
```

becomes

```
("aA" == "AA") ? "" : "aA" }
```

causing `"aA"` to assigned its current value (i.e., left unchanged).

Originally I had `str.gsub(/^..,/)`, with the anchor `^` needed to limit the replacement to the first three characters, but as there was but one (possible) replacement per string, `sub` could be used, eliminating the need for the anchor.

**Alternative**

A variant of this solution is the following:

```
a.map { |str| str.sub(/[A-Z].,/) { |s| s ? "" : s } }
```

As the block variable is either `nil` or a string beginning with a capital letter, this eliminates the need to determine, within the block, whether the string is capitalized.

Comment: It would be useful to break this down a little bit and provide some explanation.

Comment: Good idea, @Tom.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I should have done that in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
a = ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]

a.collect { |str| str.first.match(/\A[A-Z]\z/) ? (str.slice!(0..2); str) : str }

=> ["Ab,Aa", "Bb,Bd", "Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
```

Comment: The `String` class defines no `first` method. Your code raises `NoMethodError: undefined method \`first' for "Ac,Ab,Aa":String`.

Comment: Which ruby version you are using? I am using 2.0.0 and, inside rails console, it is working for me.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.1.1, but since `String#first` is a Rails extension it doesn't really matter. If you use Rails extension to answer questions that are not tagged as `ruby-on-rails` you should explicitly require necessary files, in this case: `require 'active_support/core_ext/string'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
arr.map do |item|
     item = item.gsub(/^[A-Z]../, '')
end
```

Comment: Agreed, that's how I'd have done it, OP says he wants to capture the group though as well, (I think?)

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
arr =  ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
arr.each{ |x|
    if x[0] =~ /[A-Z]/ 
      x = x[3..-1]
      puts x
    end     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest this:--

```
arr = ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]

arr.each_with_object([]){|e, o| o << e unless e[0][/[A-Z]/]}

#=> ["aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
```

And if you want to correct your method, the you can do it with either of the followings:--

1.)

```
def eliminatecolumn(arr)
  arr.map do |item| 
    if item[0]=~/[A-Z]/
     item[0..7]= ''
    end
  end
  arr.delete("")
  arr
end
```

2.)

```
def eliminatecolumn(arr)
  arr.map.with_index do |item, i| 
    if item[0][/[A-Z]/]
     arr[i] = nil
    end
  end
  arr.compact
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice ruby-way approach would be:

```
arr = ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]

arr.map! do |string|
  string.slice!(0,3) if string =~ /^[[:upper:]]/
  string
end.delete_if(&:empty?)
```

I am using regexp to check if first character is uppercase. Block need to return string after trimming, because `String#slice!` method is returning removed part of string. `Array#map!` method makes changes to the array you are iterating instead of build new one. Finally `Array#delete_if` is needed to remove strings that have no content (i.e. they return `true` value when `empty?` method is called on them).

Answer (score 1):

While the your idea is perfectly fine there are two errors in your code.

1. The expression `item[0..2] = ''` evaluates to `''`, thus for each string whose first character matches `/[A-Z]/` in `arr`, you get an empty string in the resulting array.
2. The conditional expression inside the block passed to `map` is missing an `else` clause, thus for each string that doesn't match che condition, you get a `nil` in the resulting array.

The corrected version of your code is:

```
def eliminate_column(ary)
  ary.map do |item| 
    item[0..2] = '' if item[0] =~ /[A-Z]/
    item
  end
end
```

Following the alternative I'd choose:

```
def eliminate_column(ary)
  ary.map { |s| s.sub(/\A[A-Z]../, '') }
end
eliminate_columns(arr1)
# => ["Ab,Aa", "Bb,Bd", "Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
```

It is slightly different from your solution because it leave the strings inside `ary` intact while yours modify them with the expression `item[0..2] = ''`. To reproduce the exact behaviour of your code just reaplce `sub` with `sub!`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got it, If you were wondering how to loop over the input here's a way that I would do it. (though I think I tend to favour lazy enumerators too much.

```
arr =  ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
arr.each do
  |item| 
     item.split(/,/).lazy.take_while {|x| x[0] =~ /[a-z]/}.map {|x| # Do your stuff here}.force
end
```

This won't return a map of the remaining items though but you haven't said whether you'd like them or not?